# Out of country addresses

Tags: contacts

How do I add another country to the address field on CiviCRM 5.13.5? I cannot find a way under settings to alter my options. Only "United States" appears.

Comment: were you not able to find an answer to this in the civi documentation easily? hmm. no it is not so quick to find. it is in the search results if you type "country" but well down the list: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/#localization

Answer (score 2):

It's under Administer -> Localization -> Languages, Currency, Locations. Closer to the bottom of the page.